# In the sense of Collatz

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $n=a_ka_{k-1}\ldots a_1a_0$ be a $(k+1)$ digit number.

**Step 1:** Find $a_k \times a_{k-1} \times \ldots \times a_1 \times a_0= c_tc_{t-1}\ldots c_1c_0$.

**Step 2:** Find $a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 + a_0= d_ld_{l-1}\ldots d_1d_0$.

Then form $n_1=c_tc_{t-1}\ldots c_1c_0d_ld_{l-1}\ldots d_1d_0$.

Repeat steps 1 and 2 for $n_1$ if $n_1$ is not a single digit number. Else, stop.

Examples: $1 \to 1; \ldots ; 9 \to 9;  10\to 01=1;  11\to 12 \to 23\to 65\to 3011\to 05=5 ; \ldots$

**Note:**
 All the permutations of the digits of a number yield the same result, i.e. for instance, $127,172,217,271,712,721 \to 1410\to 06$. Hence, once all numbers from 1 to 50 have been checked, we need only check 55, 66, 77, 88 and  99 to extend our result for the range 1-100.

**Facts:**
All numbers except $38$(or $83$), $66$, and $88$ converge. $38$ and $88$ fall into the 5-cycle: $$88\to 8416 \to 14417\to 11217\to 1412 \to 88$$ while $66$ falls into the interesting 1-cycle: $$3612\to 3612$$
Also $6417$ falls into the 5-cycle: $$16818\to 38424\to 76821\to 67224\to 67221\to 16818$$

**Question:** Is the Collatz phenomenon happening here?(i.e. Do all numbers yield a sequence that converges to a single digit number or a sequence that falls into a cycle?)

**My question has been answered**. But I had some thoughts going on based on my experiment: Is  the number of cycles finite?

Thanks.(MO is cool! I can't disagree.)

Comment: The Collatz process is more interesting than yours because it does not depend on the decimal representation of numbers.

Comment: No http://www.oeis.org entry.

Comment: @lhf: but the Collatz problem depends on the number "3". 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the only way that you can get a sequence which doesn't converge to a repeating cycle is if you find a sequence with unbounded elements, but it is easy to show that this is not the case. If you start with a number $n$, with $k$ digits, then the number of digits in $f(n)$ (after you perform both steps) is at most $2+\log_{10}(9^k)+\log_{10}(9k)$ which is less than $k$ for large enough $k$.

Comment: To be more precise, Mathematica tells me that $f(n)<n$ for all $n$ with at least 110 digits.

Comment: @Gjergji, thanks. I don't see why your answer is definitive. Here is why: Denote the number of digits ($1+\lfloor \log_{10}f(n)\rfloor $) by $N(f(n))$. Start with $n$ having number of digits $k$ large enough. I am okay with the proposition that $N(f(n))<k$ for $k$ large enough. Continuing the process, we may reach a number whose number of digits is not large enough. This number then may explode and surpass our original $n$. This means we now have a number whose number of digits is large enough...then back to the 'small number of digits' case...then back to the 'large number of digits' case...

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi. cont'd $\ldots$This shows why the "number of digits" argument might not be so definitive. However, your Mathematica computation seems to be in favor. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I showed that there is a number $N$ so that $f(n)<n$ for all $n>N$. This means that no matter which number you start with, at some point you will end up in the range $[1,N]$, after which there are only finitely many possibilities for the sequence to continue. Yes, after it reaches this interval it may again jump outside the interval but it will decrease again until it becomes $<N$ etc. So essentially you can see that every sequence is eventually bounded (by $\max (f(n))$ for all $n\le N$) and therefore eventually periodic.

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi. I loved your answer. I can see the reason now. On further experiment, may be there are a finite number of cycles into which a number may fall(just a thought).

Comment: Indeed.  Your observation on permutations and Gjergji's observation on the existence of N shows that there are at most on the order of N/factorial(clog_10(N)) cycles, where c is a constant less than 1, and this can probably be improved by replacing N by something like sqrt(N).  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: Also, because lots of numbers have 0's, or both a 2 and a 5, most numbers will collapse pretty quickly.  (Look up Sloane and the persistence of a number for related material.)  Even if you reorder the numbers so that you get 50 instead of 05, I still think you will get very few cycles for the reasons above.  I am now guessing that the number of cycles is more like O(log(log(N))) for N as in the comment above.  Gerhard "Round And Round We Go" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: @Gerhard, thanks. I am sorry I need some clarification. Given a number $n>N$, we know after some iteration that we will reach a number $<N$. However if the next number jumps out and coincides with one of the preceding numbers that was greater than $N$, then we will have a cycle. What is the reason for such occurrences to be finite? 

Comment: @Gerhard,thanks you very much again. For your second comment, I also observed that the occurrence of $0$ or any combination to this effect quickens convergence. "The persistence of a number" is new to me. I'll look it up. 

Comment: Because your procedure is deterministic.  Starting from within [1...N], there are only finitely many outcomes.  Starting from greater than N, there are infinitely many (finite-length before hitting a cycle) paths, but once you get to at most N, there will still be only finitely many outcomes.  Every cycle has to have a number  <= N, so there are only finitely many of them, as any two cycles having an integer m must be the same cycle. (If from N you had an infinite range of choices, that would be different; your process gives just one.)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman, thank you very much.